# How would you represent an include relationship in a UML class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a class called booking that requires a payment to be completed and also requires a confirmation to be sent. I have three classes: booking, confirmation and payment but I'm not sure how to demonstrate that the booking class requires both a payment to be completed and a confirmation to be sent. I considered using composition but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 2):

A class diagram will only show structure, but you are talking about behavior. You will show that in either a sequence or an activity diagram.

[image]

Here I made the `Confirmation` an association class which connects `Booking` and `Payment`.

[image]

And this is a simplistic representation of what happens when doing a booking.

N.B. with regards to @granier's comments:

- P. 373 of the specs

  > When a node completes execution, a token is removed from the node and tokens are offered to some or all of its outgoing ActivityEdges.
- P. 401

  > An ExecutableNode may also consume and produce data, but it must do so through related ObjectNodes.
  >
  > ...
  >
  > That is, there is an *implicit fork* of the flow of control from the ExecutableNode to its outgoing ControlFlows.

Comment: Okay so would it would just be a composition relationship where the booking cannot exist without the payment for instance?

Comment: Just forget about composition. Just make an association with the right multiplicity. That's enough for the structural part.

Comment: I added sample diagrams.

Comment: @Kilian i am not sure that you can have an object like you model, i invite you to check the norm. If i read the UML certification book, This Object creation creates a token and then that's an issue.

Comment: @granier I was uncertain about that too. But `Send confirmation` has an implicit fork (you remember?). And elements with no outgoing flow swallow the token when done (written somewhere else). So that's absolutely correct. Actually the flow to final from `Send...` could be omitted too.

Comment: @Kilian i am not sure also i have to check the point about swallow, if this is right, that's ok. But why not using a send signal in this case ? The data could be integrated in the signal.

Comment: @granier A send signal would trigger another process, but here's just an object which is created. I'm sure (as one can be) about the token (split and swallow). Too lazy at the moment to find the reference. It's somewhere in the State chapter. Anyway (even if it were wrong), the picture transports the message.

Comment: @granier I added references to my answer.

Comment: @Kilian i agree the fork, i spoke about that here but the point is what happens to the object ? It is lost ? Yes a signal should be received by someone but "send confirmation" should also sends something to someone. Another solution could be to define an output pin to "send confirmation" and then to go from this output pin to the exit ... I would not be sure of the interpretation but it would avoid the fork.

Comment: No. The object is not lost. Just the token vanishes. This is a fundamental difference. Please read the according sections which describe the semantic of the token.